# How to access associated array in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in Laravel.  I have a table, `categories`, and I am trying to access all the rows of the table in a controller, but only the last row is showing in the view.

**my Controller code:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Category;
use DB;


class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin1.create-cateogry');
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
                        'category_name' => 'required',
                    ]);
        $category_name = $request->input('category_name');
        $category=new Category;
        $category->category_name=$category_name;
        $category->url_name=$category_name;
        $category->status=1;
        $category->save();
        $success="Category Added Successfully";
        return redirect()->route('success',$success);
    }
public function view()
{


    //$categories=Category::table('categories')->get();
    $categories=DB::table('categories')->get();;
    //dd($categories);
    return view('admin1.view-category')->with('categories', $categories);
}

}
```

**and here is my view code**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">


    </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Categories</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.N.</th>
                             <th>Category Name</th>
                              <th>Url</th>
                               <th colspan="3">Action</th>
                        </tr>


                    <?php
                    $n=1;
                   // $categories->each(function($categorie) // 
                    foreach($categories as $categorie) { }
                    {?>


                        <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $n;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $categorie->category_name;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $categorie->url_name;?></td>
                        <td>Edit</td>
                        <td>Delete</td>


                        </tr>
                   <?php
                        $n++;
                    }
                    ?>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Can anyone explain to me where I am going wrong in the view action?  When I'm trying to do `dd($categories);` in action, it reflects all the records.

Answer (score 0):

For the controller:

```
public function view()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    return view("admin1.view-category", ["categories" => $categories]);
}
```

Use [blade template syntax](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade):

```
@foreach($categories as $categorie) 
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $categorie->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $categorie->category_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $categorie->url_name }}</td>
    <td>Edit</td>
    <td>Delete</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks sorry i forgot to remove the { } anyways thanks for your valuable comment